# Cannot $heroku login, authentication always fails and I am sure I have the correct credentials

Tags: macos, bash, heroku

Every time I try to use the heroku CLI to login, add keys, etc... it says that the authentication failed.  Its driving me nuts!

Does anyone have a solution to this problem, or information on how to completely reset everything that has to do with heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind!  Apparently there is something wrong on their end and they are working to resolve it.

=== Heroku Status
Development: yellow
Production:  No known issues at this time.

=== Login failures via CLI/Toolbelt  2013/03/19 02:44:29 (~ 24m+)
2013/03/19 02:44:29 (~ 24m ago)  issue  Intermittent login failures from the command-line Toolbelt client (i.e., `heroku login`).  Engineers are investigating.

cam:~ Cam$